# How to intentionally mess up a mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

How I break my mac to the point it cant be repaired without physically damaging it

Edit: Please just tell me how I could break my macbook to make if unrepairable without physical damage.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here (without already making assumptions about the solution)?

Comment: Setting aside the XY problem, this just isn't clear enough to meet the minimum site standards for a well researched question. It's just not clear what your Mac is, what your skill level is and what "cannot be repaired" means. These are commodity computers and everything can be repaired. This is just discussion bait without a serious edit to improve the quality of the question.

Comment: Your edit didn't address the issues mentioned in the comments above, it merely repeats the question again. Please reread the comments and the [faq] and edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If the Mac hardware is physically in good order and not broken, then all that remains is software, and that can always be restored.

If the internal storage (SSD, hard drive) still functions, then it can be erased, and the OS re-installed. You will then have a working Mac.

However, it remains unclear why you would want to render a Mac unrepairable for reasons that aren't unpleasant and antisocial.

Comment: Not all software can be restored. For example, if you upgrade the firmware, then the only way to go backwards is to replace the logic board.

Comment: +1 for ethical caveat. I feel uncomfortable helping out here. @DavidAnderson is correct - messing up firmware will render a mac pretty much useless